# "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled" error when I make slight change in my code

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to sightly modify the rnn.static_rnn function in Tensorflow.

The original code is as shown below:

```
def static_rnn(cell,
           inputs,
           initial_state=None,
           dtype=None,
           sequence_length=None,
           scope=None):
           .
           .
           .
    for time, input_ in enumerate(inputs):
        if time > 0:
        varscope.reuse_variables()
      # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
        call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
```

I needed another input for the static_rnn function and changed it accordingly:

```
def static_rnn(cell,
           inputs,
           past_inputs,
           initial_state=None,
           dtype=None,
           sequence_length=None,
           scope=None):
           .
           .
           .
    for time, (input_, past_input) in enumerate(tf.stack([inputs, past_inputs])):
        if time > 0:
        varscope.reuse_variables()
      # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
        call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, past_input, state)
```

The change I made is that I added "past_inputs" as another input for static_rnn.

I have tried various variations of this and I keep getting the error:

> Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

I have tried using tf.map_fn too but I encounter different problems with it. What mistake am I making? Any suggestions to write this part of the code differently?

Thanks

Comment: This generally occurs when you use a Tensor where a list or tuple would be separated into arguments or returned values.  Check the number of input arguments to the function when you call it, and verify the number of returned values at the end of the function against what you're expecting when you call it - that's usually where I see the error.  The comment about EE simply means that if you don't have the explicit values of the Tensor, they can't be dynamically slotted into multiple arguments because that information isn't available, and you'd have to do it within the formalized graph.